# please recommend an ideal software to combine several figures into one figure

Tags: png

I have three plots in png format and want them to be combined into one png file, aligned side-by-side in a line. The original png files might have quite wide white boundaries and I hope they can be optimizedly cropped when the software reads them in. I hope the software provides mouse support so that I can allign/resize these plots as I wish. I also hope the generated file would not lose their resolution. I know under mac there is such a tool (may not crop the white area), but don't know whether similar tools exist under windows or linux.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what you have researched and tried, otherwise this question will only rack up downvotes.

Comment: Just about *any* raster image editing application can do what you ask.

Comment: Imagemagick is the tool for this job!

Comment: @Michael Schumacher, basically powerpoint and then print to pdf format. So white space etc are an issue, frequent transfer between formats also causes losing resolution. Photoshop is too complicated for me. Inkscape seems to do the job, but seems not as convenient as gimp suggested by user287001.

Comment: @joojaa , which one is more user-friendly between imagemagick and gimp? I actually heard of both these two, but only used to view figures instead of editing them.

Comment: @bsmile imagemagick once you have done your first merge because all other merges are the same. Never do the work again. In gimp you get to work it every time.

Comment: This question is somehow basic, but valid. The user is simply asking a recommended software. That is not "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all photo editig tools do this. Photoshop belong to the high end and it costs real money, but it still is the industry standard. Gimp is freeware and its also has pro quality capablities. And in low end commercial software, there are many others, for example Affinity Photo

You can run free demo versions of the commercial software to see, what is suitable for you. Watch the tutorials to get started fast.

The workflow:

- open the photos and crop the extras off
- Check the pixel dimensions of your photos - the interesting areas must be the same plusminus 50% Otherwise it's possible that you must enlargen one too much and that can make it unsharp.
- create an empty new document that has the wanted total pixel dimensions
- copy your photos to  independent new layers onto the empty one
- move and finetune the sizes as you will
- combine the layers to one (do not flatten, only merge if you like to save the transparency)
- save as PNG

Comment: Thanks for suggesting gimp. I think this software really works to my need. Even better, I can do the image manipulations within the same file but on different layers, so no need to copy around, to reduce one chance of losing resolution. One issue I came up with is, when I select an area, rescale to smaller, I found the resolution seriously deteriarates. How can I possibly fix that? Should I open a huge canvas to maintain the resolutions in order to combine several figures together in order to maintain resolution?

Comment: @bsmile Big enough canvas is the right way . But it does not help if you have some original images that have too low pixel dimensions. Allways check the dimensions as pixels to be sure. "How many centimeters or inches" does not tell the resolution because the pixels/inch or DPI variable can be whatever. For high quality printing at least 300 DPI is the norm, onscreen only 72 or 75 DPI is ok.